# extracting the "lower"/"terminal" elements in a list in R

Tags: r, list

Is there a best way to extract the lower elements of a list?
For example this list people has a series of "peoples", each with a number "R" attached as `people[[i]]$Expertise$R`.
Is there a best way to extract them as a vector?
I hoped to use rlist and its good for loads of things I needed but I can't see a function for this.
Here is an example doing what I need but maybe suboptimally:

```
#https://renkun.me/rlist-tutorial/Features/Filtering.html
#install.packages("rlist")

library(rlist)
people <- list.load("http://renkun.me/rlist-tutorial/data/sample.json")
length(people)
str(people)
people[[1]][[1]]$R
str(list.filter(people, Age >= 25))

Rskill<-numeric()
for(i in 1:length(people)) 
Rskill<-c(Rskill,people[[i]]$Expertise$R)
Rskill

unlist(lapply(1:length(people),function(i) people[[i]]$Expertise$R))
```

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example. http://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/1691723

Comment: @Sathish: OP's example appears reproducible to me

Comment: I'm not familiar with `rlist`, but you can make your `lapply()` a bit simpler and more robust with: `vapply(people, function(p) p$Expertise$R, integer(1))`

Comment: thanks, a p o m, vapply looks useful  - the main difference to lapply seems to be you can specify whats returned ?

Comment: @apom it would be better, if OP provided data using `dput` and the desired output, otherwise people will tend to assume a lot and guess work will come in.

Answer (score 0):

I think sapply is the simplest way to extract R values as a vector:

```
sapply(people,function(l)l$Expertise$R)
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the rlist package, but you may extract the Rskill via

```
sapply(people, function(x) x$Expertise$R)
```

or, if you prefer a loop, with

```
Rskill <- numeric(length(people))
for (i in seq_along(people))
    Rskill[[i]] <- people[[c(i, 4, 1)]]
```

The latter works because lists are 'vectors' in the sense that you can meaningfully address (e.g., extract)
the n-th element. In a nested list, you can access a single element by a numeric vector.

Answer (score 0):

`vapply()` is a more robust alternative to your `lapply()`, ensuring the type of the output (here, `"integer"`):

```
vapply(people, function(p) p$Expertise$R, integer(1))
# [1] 2 3 1
```

`rlist` appears to provide similar functionality with `list.mapv()`:

```
list.mapv(people, .$Expertise$R, "integer")
# [1] 2 3 1

# Or even simpler, saving typing two characters ;-)
list.mapv(people, Expertise$R, "integer")
# [1] 2 3 1
```